# Computation: better to truncate before insertion or let MySQL truncate?

Tags: php, mysql, string, truncation, tinytext

Difficult question to phrase, so let me explain.

As part of an RSS caching system I'm inserting a lot of rows into a DB, several times a day. One of the columns is 'snippet', for the `description` node in the RSS feeds.

Sometimes this node is far longer than I want, since the corresponding DB column is type "tiny text" (max: 255 chars).

So, in terms of computation/memory, **is it better for me to truncate via PHP before insertion, or just feed the whole, too-long string to MySQL and have *it* do the truncation?**

Both of course work, but I wondered if one was better practice than the other.

Comment: It is probably never good to allow for truncation unless you absolutely have to, I would suggest doing truncation outside of the database before you insert it but it really depends on the program you are using, either way it is probably best to test it and find out.

Comment: To me, it seems better practice for you to adjust the data first in PHP. PHP is communicating to MySQL through a socket connection. If you pass the longer data value from PHP to MySQL, you're expending additional resources needlessly during the transport.

Comment: mysql will just chop at the limit and can sever words. if you want "nice" readable text afterwards, then you should do the truncation in PHP where you have some control over where the text terminates.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys. PHP it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases like this it's probably best to measure. If you don't notice a difference then it doesn't matter.

My intuition tells me that, since your snippet size is very small and the plain text can be very big it would be better to truncate before hand. Take the performance hit in PHP so you don't spend a lot of time sending a large query to MySQL.

For readability and code clarity it would also be better to do the truncation in PHP because that makes it explicit. You can even do clever truncating by word or by sentence.

Comment: @Utkanos:  besides chopping by word, you might also append "..." so there is an easy way to know that happened.